# How to print a list of filename from a directory by date in C?

Tags: c, sorting, date, filenames

I wanna print the name of every filename from a directory by date. I have sorted every date but I wanna associate every name with its date. Is there a function or a method to do that?

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 100

char SORTNAME() {
    DIR *dir = opendir(".");
    if (dir) {
        char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
        struct stat info;
        struct dirent *s_dir;
        int buf = BUFFERSIZE;
        time_t *Time = malloc(sizeof(time_t) * buf);
        int i = 0;

        while ((s_dir = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
            if (s_dir->d_name[0] != '.') {
                sprintf(buffer, "%s", s_dir->d_name);
                stat(buffer, &info);
                Time[i] = info.st_mtime;
                i++;
            }
        } 

        int size = i;
        int h, j, k, min;
        time_t t;

        for (j = 0; j < size - 1; j++) {
            min = j;
            for (k = j + 1; k < size; k++) {
                if (Time[k] > Time[min]) {
                    min = k;
                }
            }
            t = Time[min];
            Time[min] = Time[j];
            Time[j] = t;
        }
    }
}
```

It's a bit rudimental but it works.

Comment: Use a `struct` for your data, then do `man qsort`. And you're still not "connecting" anything.

Comment: Storing the times into an array is a good idea, but yeah: then you lose the connection with the file name. Hence the suggestion to use a `struct`. (Without is also possible, but then you'd need a third array containing indices into the separate ('unconnected') `name` and `Time` arrays. Don't do that. Use a `struct`.)

Comment: This is strange: The code you show is capable to store as many dates as the maximum possible length of a file's name  -1.

Comment: Also, what is this `bufferTime`?

Comment: C itself has no concept of directories, your are using some OS specific stuff. Please tag your question with that OS and maybe also remove the "C" tag, because your question seems not about the programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow these steps:

- store the filenames and the dates in an array of structures, reallocating the array if there are more files than expected. Make sure you allocate copies of the filenames.
- sort the array with `qsort` and an appropriate sorting function.  Try using different sorting functions to sort by file time, name, extension...
- print the entries in the order of the array.  Converting the file time can be done with `strftime()`

Comment: I'll try to store name and date in a struct. If I put every date in an array, I sort it (like in the code) and I call for each date his name? It should work?

Comment: @HugoB: you can modify your program by adding another array for the copies of the filenames and swap the entries in this array in sync with the `Time` array.  Yet it is simpler and more efficient to use `qsort` on an array of structures.

Comment: It's absolutely true. If I have other problems about the program I'll write here

Comment: Sorry If I write again here, my old mind needs a help. I'm trying both the methods and In each I have found problems. If I use an array to store the names and I use `char *Name = malloc(sizeof(char) *buf);` and `Name[j]=s_dir->d_name;` doesn't work... I tryed to make a struct with `char name; time_t time` but I can't fill it.

Comment: @HugoB: It should be `char *Name = malloc(sizeof(char*) * buf);` and `Name[j] = strdup(s_dir->d_name);`.